# Leer una variable introducida cada 1 seg en PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy queriendo que se lea de forma automática cada un segundo una variable por el momento lo estoy leyendo cada vez que se quiere al hacer clic en el botón la variable lo introduzco por medio de la variable entrada y lo imprimo en pantalla con la variable palabra, a continuación dejo el código

```
import tkinter as tk
app = tk.Tk()
palabra = tk.StringVar(app)
entrada=tk.StringVar(app)

def cambiarPalabra():
  palabra.set(entrada.get())

tk.Button(
  app,
  text="Boton",
  font=("Courier", 14),
  bg="#00a8e8",
  fg="white",
  command= cambiarPalabra,
).pack(
  fill=tk.BOTH,
  expand=False,
)

tk.Label(
   app,
text="La etiqueta",
textvariable=palabra,
fg="black",
bg="white",
justify="center"
).pack(
  fill=tk.BOTH,
  expand=False,
)

tk.Entry(
 fg="white",
 bg="black",
 justify="center",
 textvariable=entrada
).pack(
 fill=tk.BOTH,
 expand=False,
)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Usa el método universal [after](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/la-funcion-after-en-tkinter/) junto a la función encargada de leer la variable. Por otro lado, si queres mostrar el nuevo valor de la variable cada vez que cambie, también hay una forma.

Comment: Cuál sería la forma de mostrar cada vez que cambie el valor, ya que ya use el after antes de ejecutar la línea app.mainloop(), lo que hice fue: app.after(200, cambiarPalabra)

Comment: Usa `tuvariable.trace_add("write", funcion_que_actualiza)`. "write" indica que la función debe de ejecutarse cuando la variable es escrita. La función debe recibir 3 argumentos (no suelen ser relevantes, así que puedes usar *args para capturar todos).